# Place a movie clip on the stage via Actionscript

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I have an assignment where at one point, I have to put a movieclip on the stage. I can't just drag it and place it and set it to visible at some point in time, I have to use Actionscript to pull it from the library and make it appear on the stage at certain X/Y coordinates.

My assignment says that the function `attachMovie()` would be useful, but I don't see how, since that's used for attaching movieclips to other movieclips...

Can anybody help here?

Comment: Yes, Actionscript 2 in CS3 on Windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use attachMovie with the stage.

In AS2 is something like:

```
_root.attachMovie("name_of_the_original_clip", "name_of_the_new_clip", _root.getNextHighestDepth());
```

In AS2 the stage is considered a MovieClip in itself.
I hope it helps!

Comment: Indeed, also, the reason it didn't work was because I forgot to add linkage...

Comment: I just changed the variable names. Sorry, I typed too quickly & it's difficult remember the old AS2! :)

Comment: No problems. I deleted my answer below and the original comment here. They're redundant now. :) Thanks for the update!

Comment: What if you want to attach the MovieClip to a nested MovieClip on the stage.  For instance this doesn't work for me: _root.mc.attachMovie(...), i receive undefined, why?

Comment: The problem in your case seems to be _root.mc, not the attachMovie call. Make sure it exists before attaching a movie. If this is the first thing you do when the movie starts, make sure the whole movie is loaded before making the call.